# Making a DIY wind generator for kid's project. How can we improve it?

Tags: generator, flux

My boy wants to make a wind generator and we have a 3D printer.

We have decided to go with an axial flux style 140mm diameter with 12 iron free coils (4 per phase) so it can turn easily. Without gears, we get can get 500RPM but normally maximum of 300RPM. We have done 300 turns per coil using 0.35 wire. We have eight 30mm round x 5mm  neodymium magnets.

What would be best to do to increase power as we are not getting a lot?

1. Change wire size
2. Use twelve 40x10mmx5mm bar magnets
3. More turns (but not much room for more)
4. We used triangle coils.  Would round ones be better?

I am not an engineer just trying to remember from college and please my boy. Any advice would be a great help if more than one please put them in priority.

Update:

[image]

This is the design we have. We get 12 volts but only 270mA.

If we use 12 x 30mm bar magnets they would line up with the flux lines better so maybe that's where we failed the most.

Comment: Without being able to see what you're doing it's hard to say.  Can you _edit your question_ with some pictures (you can drag & drop pictures into the question), and be sure to include dimensions.

Comment: Craig, when worried about not getting a lot from your efforts, the very first thing I'd do is work through the required theories involved in making predictions. (Or buy a professional product I could use to calibrate results.) Only then can you know if you are getting close, or not, to what *can* be done. Otherwise, you just can't know. Ungeared, when you are getting 300 RPM what is the wind speed at that time? What's the blade diameter into the wind? Do you have a specific pitch? Or is it variable? Have you looked at the old NACA (pre-NASA) tables for wind blades?

Comment: Can you show the magnetic flux path? Most improvements are hidden there

Comment: Quality of magnets.  Coil size relative to magnets.  More turns.  Finer wire.  So many things can be poorly done.  Bigger wind mill.  Put your boy on the roof (maybe not the best idea).  Pictures with dimensions will help.

Comment: To get maximum power from a wind generator or photovoltaic array, you need to use a converter that adjusts its impedance for optimum voltage and current. This is known as MPPT. You can get an idea of the principle by reading the open circuit voltage and the short circuit current (or where the windmill generates maximum current). Somewhere between these extremes will be the maximum power point. It's also where source and load impedance are matched. https://www.renewablewise.com/mppt-charge-controller/

Comment: Here is a better explanation for wind power, and a project you can build: https://www.instructables.com/MPPT-Charge-Controller-for-Small-Wind-Turbines/

Comment: The easiest way to demonstrate a wind generator is to get a window fan (nothing fancy with digital LED's... cheapest one you can find).  Install it, wait for the wind to start blowing and causing it to turn, you'll be able to measure an AC voltage across the power cord blades.

Comment: May get some ideas : https://thumbwind.com/2020/07/21/diy-renewable-energy-projects/

Comment: "*We get 12 volts but only 270mA.*" I think that's pretty good from the results I've seen from other home setups.

Comment: But that’s only 3.24 watts isn’t it? Our aim was 50w-100w

Comment: I have just ordered a mppt. I tried using 12 magnets today but get nothing so design must be cancelling flux they cost me £50 this is adding up fast for a little project

Comment: I found a wind power calculator that might help determine how close your design is to the theoretical maximum. The main considerations are wind speed and fan area. Power is proportional to cube of wind speed, and is in the order of 100 W/m^2 at 10 MPH. http://windpower.generatorguide.net/wind-speed-power.html

Answer (score 2):

**1. Get an MPPT**

Probably impractical for a school project, but will provide a big increase.

**2. Put the stator and rotor closer together.**

Even a tiny bit closer will make a difference.

**3. Change the blades.**

It is important to get the right blades for your conditions (windspeed).

**4. Add a second stator to the other side of your magnets.**

Double the magnetic flux that you are taking advantage of.

**5. Better magnets**

Since its a school project, this extra cost may not be worth it to you.

Here's a good paper you can reference:
https://we.riseup.net/assets/233731/Axial+Flux+Permanent+Magnet+Generator+Design.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you have a 3d printer, just wondering, as you don't mention the rotor, if you're using a printed plastic rotor for the magnets rather than an iron one? this would dramatically reduce the efficiency....just a thought.
Also looking at the diagram, 12 bar magnets 30mm long would seem to fit better than 40mm ones, and would be cheaper too

Good luck with the project, I'm doing something very similar but making a VAWT just to supplement solar ( no direct sun from Nov-Mar )  charging at a very low level to a 69Ah battery